# Passing user credentials to a third party API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an .Net Core 2.1 Web API, which in turn makes a request to a 3rd party API.

My API and the 3rd party API have their own authentication schemes.

as an example:

when a user makes this request to my API:

```
POST https://www.my-api.com/api/messages
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json

{ 
   "ThirdPartyAccount": "Account123", 
   "Username": "3pusername", 
   "Password": "3ppa$$word", 
   "Message": "Hello there!!"
}
```

My api internally creates a request to the 3rd party API in the following manner:

```
POST https://www.3party-api.com/api/accounts/Account123/messages
Authorization: Basic YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

Message=Hello there!!
```

Note that "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" above is the base64 encoded version of this string : `3pusername:3ppa$$word`

As you see, currently i'm accepting the 3rd party account number, username, and password as part of the json body of my API. the credentials to the 3rd party API is different than those to my own.

It feels like accepting these details in the body as json text is not the correct approach although all of these services are TLS1.2.

What is the correct way to accept credentials in a use-case where you need to  propagate/pass-through to a 3rd party?

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? Think about possible options of transfering data to a server (query parameters, body: json, form data, headers etc.) and think what's wrong with the current approach compared to others.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a best practice around this scenario. perhaps a specific header that i could use.